# Viewing topology while working

Tags: mirror, topology

when I try to model from tutorials the instructors' topology will show on both sides of a mirrored object, and won't be as hidden with gray in areas. I can't figure out how to set that up. [image: topology views]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've got to enable this display method in the mirror modifier by hitting this small icon:

[image]

Comment: Also, is there a way to see the vertices through the gray mesh? Quite a few of them get hidden by gray blotching when I model. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes of course! :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHnwg.png Just press this small button and x-ray is enabled.